# How to integrate $\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ using substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

Trying to integrate $$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx = \int \frac{1}{x}\sin'(x) dx$$ by substituting $\sin(x)$, but it either becomes more complicated or I end up with a $\frac{1}{x}$ still in the integral.

Comment: [Not "possible"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to find an antiderivative of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ in term of "elementary functions".

This is a consequence of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)). See link to article for details.

Comment: Does that mean that integrating $$\int \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}dx$$ with substitution is also impossible? Because I split it up and thought it would be easier to integrate $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ separately...

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: You might want to refer to them as _elementary_ functions, because _simple_ functions often refer to other categories (e.g. in measure theory).

Comment: @edmz You're right! I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As noted the indefinite integral
$$
\int \frac{\cos x}{x}\;dx
$$
is not an elementary function.  But it is useful enough that it has been given a name, the ["cosine integral"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) function, $\mathrm{Ci}(x)$.  It is conventional to fix the constant of integration so that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \mathrm{Ci}(x) = 0$.  So we may define
$$
\mathrm{Ci}(x) = -\int_x^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}\;dt
$$
In fact, this definition makes sense for $x$ in the complex plane, with a cut along the negative real axis.